# Access GCP Secret during Cloud Build build step

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Lets say I have a cloudbuild.yaml file that looks like this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: build
    args: ['build', '-t', 'us.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/image_name', '--build-arg', 'secret=$$SECRET', '.']
    secretEnv: ['SECRET']
 
images:
  - 'us.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/image_name'

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/project/secrets/my_secret/versions/latest
    env: 'SECRET'
```

Right now, the --build-arg is assigning to the Docker `secret` arg the value `$SECRET` instead of the value actually stored in the secret. How can I access the secret value during this step? All of the examples I can find online say to add a bash entrypoint however only for steps that aren't actually doing the build call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a usual issue with Cloud Build and Secret Manager integration. You can access to the secret only in a script, not in entry-point and arguments (your case)

Try that

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    id: build
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: 
      - -c
      - |
          docker build -t us.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/image_name --build-arg secret=$$SECRET .
    secretEnv: ['SECRET']
```

Comment: I get an error when doing this:

`Starting Step #0 - "build"
Step #0 - "build": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0 - "build": bad flag syntax: -----END
Step #0 - "build": See 'docker build --help'.`

Comment: Seems I got the above error because my secret starts with "--" which was being interpreted as an argument

Comment: You can add your secret between double quote `secret="$$SECRET"`

Comment: Yup, that is what I did to fix the error. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're a life saver - However I can now access the environment variable from my dockerfile, but is it really safe then ? Is the layer of this image removed after, or is the variable hidden to someone who might inspect the image ? Would greatly appreciate if anyone take the time to answer me <3

Comment: The layers keep only the file, not the in-memory variables. So, all depends on what you do with your secret

Comment: Thanks for this. Nothing about this in their docs? Frustrating to waste so much time on something so trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for assigning secrets to docker args seems to be slightly different to that for normal environment variables. The following snippet is taken from a working project of my own and correctly accesses the secret, and you can see the difference compared to the normal environment variables:

```
...
    env:
      - PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID
      - NO_DEPLOY=$_NO_DEPLOY
      - NO_E2E=$_NO_E2E
    secretEnv:
      - "EXAMPLE_API_KEY"
    args:
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/api
      - --cache=true
      - --build-arg=PROJECT_ID
      - --build-arg=EXAMPLE_API_KEY
      - --build-arg=NO_DEPLOY
      - --build-arg=NO_E2E

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/example-api-key/versions/latest
      env: "EXAMPLE_API_KEY"
...
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but now I just get `secret` assigned to `SECRET` still not containing the actual value in `SECRET`

Comment: Are you KIDDING ME?! Wow, can't believe I didn't think of this.

Comment: The reason it works: "You may also use the --build-arg flag without a value, in which case the value from the local environment will be propagated into the Docker container being built:"

Comment: No idea why `--build-arg=FOO=$$EXAMPLE_API_KEY` doesn't substitute properly though.

Comment: Found this after wasting several hours failing to pass secrets via build-arg, thank you Mark!