# cloud build pass secret env to dockerfile

Tags: docker, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am using google cloud build to build a docker image and deploy in cloud run. The module has dependencies on Github that are private. In the `cloudbuild.yaml` file I can access secret keys for example the Github token, but I don't know what is the correct and secure way to pass this token to the `Dockerfile`.

I was following this official guide but it would only work in the `cloudbuild.yaml` scope and not in the `Dockerfile`. [Accessing GitHub from a build via SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build)

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA", "."]

  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: [ "push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA" ]

  - name: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: [
      "run", "deploy", "$REPO_NAME",
      "--image", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA",
      "--platform", "managed",
      "--region", "us-east1",
      "--allow-unauthenticated",
      "--use-http2",
    ]

images:
  - gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/GITHUB_USER/versions/1
      env: "GITHUB_USER"
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/GITHUB_TOKEN/versions/1
      env: "GITHUB_TOKEN"
```

Dockerfile

```
# [START cloudrun_grpc_dockerfile]
# [START run_grpc_dockerfile]
FROM golang:buster as builder

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Create /root/.netrc cred github
RUN echo machine github.com >> /root/.netrc
RUN echo login "GITHUB_USER" >> /root/.netrc
RUN echo password "GITHUB_PASSWORD" >> /root/.netrc

# Config Github, this create file /root/.gitconfig
RUN git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com/".insteadOf "https://github.com/"

# GOPRIVATE
RUN go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/org/repo

# Do I need to remove the /root/.netrc file? I do not want this information to be propagated and seen by third parties.

# Retrieve application dependencies.
# This allows the container build to reuse cached dependencies.
# Expecting to copy go.mod and if present go.sum.
COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Build the binary.
# RUN go build -mod=readonly -v -o server ./cmd/server
RUN go build -mod=readonly -v -o server

# Use the official Debian slim image for a lean production container.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/debian
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds
FROM debian:buster-slim
RUN set -x && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the binary to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=builder /app/server /server

# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["/server"]

# [END run_grpc_dockerfile]
# [END cloudrun_grpc_dockerfile]
```

After trying for 2 days I have not found a solution, the simplest thing I could do was to generate the `vendor` folder and commit it to the repository and avoid `go mod download`.

Answer (score 11):

You have several way to do things.

With Docker, when you run a build, you run it in an isolated environment (it's the principle of isolation). So, you haven't access to your environment variables from inside the build process.

To solve that, you can use [build args](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) and put your secret values in that parameter.

But, there is a trap: you have to use bash code and not built in step code in Cloud Build. Let me show you

```
# Doesn't work
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    secretEnv: ["GITHUB_USER","GITHUB_TOKEN"]
    args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA", "--build-arg=GITHUB_USER=$GITHUB_USER,GITHUB_TOKEN=$GITHUB_TOKEN","."]

# Working version
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    secretEnv: ["GITHUB_USER","GITHUB_TOKEN"]
    entrypoint: bash
    args: 
     - -c
     - |
        docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA --build-arg=GITHUB_USER=$$GITHUB_USER,GITHUB_TOKEN=$$GITHUB_TOKEN .
```

You can also perform the actions outside of the Dockerfile. It's roughly the same thing: load a container, perform operation, load another container and continue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had already thought about --build-args but somewhere I had read that it was not safe because the keys could be seen in some log. The last thing you wrote was about skipping the `Dockerfile` and doing everything in the `cloudbuild.yaml` using the golang builder image that already exists. I had thought about this last one because it has many advantages in my use case but I don't know if it is practical, now could you write an example for us of what this would look like without a `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. This was very helpful. One small typo: it should be "--build-arg" not "--build-args".

Comment: This is not working in my case, all the args passed that way are empty when I echo them in the Dockerfile...

Comment: Thanks @csf, I didn't notice you comment earlier!!

Comment: @WojciechOwczarczyk, should be because I made a type in my code (see CSF commend)

Comment: FYI for anyone looking at this, it is indeed possible to pass secrets in build-args without reverting to bash code using https://stackoverflow.com/a/71054741/1239542 (as I found out after wasting an embarrassing amount of time trying to make it work)