# Using secrets from GCP Secret Manager in Helm GCP Cloud Builder

Tags: kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-build

I have cloudbuild.yaml file where I'm trying use helm [image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/helm) 
Inside my step I want to have access to secrets from GCP Secret Manager but I cannot use it in regular way silimary to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71054568/access-gcp-secret-during-cloud-build-build-step/71055227#71055227). 
Is it possible to use "helm step" with secrets from GCP SM? 
Something like this:

```
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/helm
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - -c
  - |
      helm upgrade $_NAME ./deployment/charts/$_NAME --namespace $_NAMESPACE --set secret.var3="$$VAR3"
```

[EDIT] 
to be more precise how my cloudbuild looks like and how it should 
when I use "helm step" in classic way:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/helm
    args:
      - upgrade
      - "$_NAME"
      - "./deployment/charts/$_NAME"
      - "--namespace"
      - "$_NAMESPACE"
      - "--set"
      - "secret.var3=$$VAR3"
    env:
      - "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=$_GKE_LOCATION"
      - "CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=$_GKE_CLUSTER"
    secretEnv: ['VAR3']
    id: Apply deploy
substitutions:
  _GKE_LOCATION: europe-west3-b
  _GKE_CLUSTER: cluster-name
  _NAME: "test"
  _NAMESPACE: "test"
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/test-var-3/versions/latest
      env: 'VAR3'
options:
  substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
```

step works fine but my variable VAR3 is equal to "$VAR3" not to value what hide behind, so according to documentation I try use something like this:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/helm
    entrypoint: 'helm'
    args:
      - |
        upgrade $_NAME ./deployment/charts/$_NAME --namespace $_NAMESPACE --set secret.var3="$$VAR3"
    env:
      - "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=$_GKE_LOCATION"
      - "CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=$_GKE_CLUSTER"
    secretEnv: ['VAR3']
    id: Apply deploy
substitutions:
  _GKE_LOCATION: europe-west3-b
  _GKE_CLUSTER: cluster-name
  _NAME: "test"
  _NAMESPACE: "test"
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/test-var-3/versions/latest
      env: 'VAR3'
options:
  substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
```

but then I got an error:

> UPGRADE FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get
> "http://localhost:8080/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080:
> connect: connection refused

Comment: Have you gone through this [github](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1126) issue?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to use the **secretEnv** as shown in the example

Example :

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'docker login --username=$$USERNAME --password=$$PASSWORD']
  secretEnv: ['USERNAME', 'PASSWORD']
```

Read more about it : https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#access-utf8-secrets

Comment: sorry, this is only small piece of my cloudbuild.yaml file, I have secretEnv, availableSecrets and I believe other necessary parts, my problem is when I use bash in helm i got error:
"UPGRADE FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused"
so I think the problem is in what happen before helm command is start

Comment: mkae sure you are attaching the kubeconfig with steps, it failing maybe due to not getting kubeconfig.

Comment: `substitutions:``_CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE: us-central1-c`,`_CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER: standard-cluster-1`

Comment: forgive me for not being precise, I have corrected the question